# Repeated w3wp.exe in Task Manager

Tags: iis, asp.net

If I have the poolname "WApp1" configured with a single application "WebS1" then why do I see 2 processes running in the Task Manager?

w3wp.exe -app "WApp1" -v "v40" -I webengine4.dll -a \. \ pipexx1 -h "path \ WebS1.config" -m0 -t510 -ta1

and the other similar

w3wp.exe -app "WApp1" -v "v40" -I webengine4.dll -a \. \ pipexx2 -h "path \ WebS1.config" -m0 -t510 -ta1

Thaks.

Comment: what is application pool->advanced setting->maximum worker processes set to? it defaults to 1. if its greater than 1, you have configured a web-garden.

Comment: Yes, the maximum worker proceses is set to 2. Is there more than 1 process running is it by default or does it depend on the requests or other thing that are activated?

Comment: It doesn't really auto-scale if that's what you are asking. see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

When an IIS server Application Pool is set to `MaxProcesses > 1` you have established a "web garden", A process model that allows an web application to run as 1 or more processes on a single server. For the most part, this is not a useful technology, and you will find many wise people across the internet telling you that its almost certainly not worth doing. Web Gardens are thematically simmilar to the multi-server architecture called "Web Farms" with all the drawbacks (like the need for external session state persistence) and few of the advantages. Google web garden and you will see the many detractors.

The actual number of processes running at a time is determined by whether the hardware is [NUMA-capable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access), and what specific NUMA-related settings are used. see here for more details: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-multicore-scaling-on-numa-hardware-with-iis-8

> When this configuration is set to 0 on non-NUMA hardware, the default
> value of 1 is used. When it is set to 0 on NUMA hardware, IIS will
> launch as many worker processes as there are NUMA nodes on the system
> so that there is a 1:1 affinity between the worker processes and NUMA
> nodes. On such systems, you should set the maxProcesses value to 0 to
> achieve maximum performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. And how is the execution of the web application divided into different processes?.
The issue arises because I am checking the configuration of the site because when it is observed that the site is slow then problems with session data appear. Does having maximum worker processes> 1 and running in different processes lead to session problems before special circumstances such as when the system slows down?

Comment: Session is by default in "InProc-mode" which literally means that the session memory is In the process. when you have one process, the app has consistent access to session memory, but if the app is run as multiple processes, the user's session may become fragmented between processes, with some here, and some there, and neither process can access the whole of it. when multiple processes (or servers) are used, you must externalize the session storage so its available to all processes. options include ASPNet State Server, SQLServer DB, and Redis Cache. SQLServer and Redis are the most scalable.